# IntelliJ IDEA: Exclude packages while running code coverage

Tags: intellij-idea, code-coverage

Is there anyway we can exclude specific packages while running code coverage using IntelliJ IDEA as coverage runner?
There is an option under Run/Debug Configurations > Coverage, that allows us to include classes/packages, but it would be very tedious to include about a few hundred packages to exclude just a few.

Answer (score 6):

There is probably no a way to match the packages that you want to include with a few wildcards? If you want to exclude one package from five packages (a, b, c, d, and e), this is the only option that I have found so far (in the "Run/Debug Configurations" dialog):

```
com.stackoverflow.a.*
com.stackoverflow.b.*
com.stackoverflow.d.*
com.stackoverflow.e.*
```

This is rather clumsy indeed.

When I run with code coverage (with a different configuration), the following output is shown:

```
D:\Programs\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\bin\java [...]
---- IntelliJ IDEA coverage runner ---- 
sampling ...
include patterns:
com\.stackoverflow\.q35257485\..*
com\.stackoverflow\.q34245660\.AnimatedBoxman(\$.*)*
exclude patterns:
Process finished with exit code 0
```

The "exclude patterns:" line gives the impression that it should be possible to exclude packages and/or classes, but I see no way to do this (in the "Run/Debug Configurations" dialog).

Comment: Makes sense..I'll try to find out this hidden feature of "exclude patterns".